# Zooming messes up display:table on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, tablerow, tablecell

Take this CSS snippet:

```
.table {
    display:table;
}
.table-row {
    display: table-row;
}
.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Alongside with some HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">
            <label>Label One</label>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">
            <label>Label Two</label>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">
            <label>Label Three pushes this table</label>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">
            <label>Label Four</label>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">
            <label>Label Five</label>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's what it looks like with zoom: 100%:

[image]

Now, I will zoom in the page to 400%:

[image]

When I reset zoom back to 100% this is what I see:

[image]

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ns2r/embedded/result/) I used for this.

This messes up on Chrome 28, 29, and 30, it works fine on Firefox, Safari, Opera, and yes, **Internet Explorer** does not mess up the padding of these cell-rows.

Besides the obvious solution of *not* using `display:table/table-row/table-cell`, how can change the html/css in a way in which Chrome will respect spacing, regardless of zoom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you are using doesn't look like tabular, but there are various ways to achieve the above. You can simple use a list and spans to align. So instead of using this

```
<div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
        <label>Label Three pushes this table</label>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>Hello</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Hello</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </li>
    <!-- Some more li elements here -->
</ul>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2CgPJ/)(Looks pretty neat)

You can also use the below CSS to control the element spacings

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

ul li {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/2CgPJ/1/)

---

Still if you want to stick to tabular layout, I would suggest you to use `table` element here instead of using a whole lot of html and classes for a single `cell`.

For example

```
<div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
        <label>Label Two</label>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Can be simply written as (Feels lot cleaner)

```
<tr>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

---

Some CSS optimization...

If you want to target the `div` which is a direct child to `.table` you can use

```
.table > div {
   /* This way you can remove all classes with name table-row */
}
```

To target the cells, you can remove `table-cell` class and use

```
.table > div > div {
   /* This way you can remove all classes with name table-cell*/
}
```